# Merging two shapefiles using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, merge, syntaxerror

I have two point features with names `o.shp` and `d.shp`. I want to merge both of these files and create a new shapefile with merged attributes.

How do I do that?

Tried code that did not work:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(["o.shp", "d.shp"], "C:/GIS/m.shp"))
```

Which gave an error:

> Error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have too many closing parentheses in your code:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(["o.shp", "d.shp"], "C:/GIS/m.shp"))
                                                          ^
```

Remove the extra `)`

```
arcpy.Merge_management(["o.shp", "d.shp"], "C:/GIS/m.shp")
```